# sass : get child's property from inside parent styling

Tags: html, css, sass

i have a group of cards with specific class for each ,
they all have a uniting general class

each specific card needs a border that is slightly darker than its background-color

so is there a way to make the general class styling apply a border that is based on the current background-color using sass

```
.general{
  display:flex; /*bla bla bla*/
  border:10px solid darken( *insert specific color here* , 10% );
}
.general.specific-1{
  background-color:red;
}
.general.specific-2{
  background-color:blue;
}
.general.specific-3{
  background-color:crimson;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `@for` loop in `sass`.

```html
<div>
  <div class="container"></div>
  <div class="container"></div>
  <div class="container"></div>
  <div class="container"></div>
  <div class="container"></div>
</div>
```

set the `background-color` of first `div` whatever you want (I chose red). Now iterate through `5` (or desired number of) elements starting from `2nd` because you already set color for `1st` element.

```scss
.container {
  width: 100px;
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
  border: 10px solid red;
  
  @for $i from 2 through 5 {
    &:nth-child(#{$i}) {
      border: 10px solid darken(red, $i * 5%);
    }
  }
}
```

**Output**

[image: Desired Output]

**P.S** - I could have created snippet but the the default editor does not support `sass`. Although I created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tf7sbur1/)